# AngularJS display svg file on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have an angularJS service that reads data from a json file and returns me an object with a few SVG image file names.

I have a ng-repeat on the return object to look and display all the SVG files on the page.

Here is my ng-repeat on my template

```
<div ng-repeat="items in libCtrl.categories track by $index">
  <div ng-include="img/library/items.categoryImage"></div>
</div>
```

This code does not display any SVG image file on the page.
But if I hardcode the value of the file names on the ng-include it works.

```
<div ng-repeat="items in libCtrl.categories track by $index">
  <div ng-include="'img/library/myfile.svg'"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get it to work using the data from my items.categoryImage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIuR359PBjSd9TuKBhii?p=preview).

Use `<div ng-include="'img/library/' + items.categoryImage"></div>`